# how handleSuccess gets the resolved value in js?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have been going in circles trying to deeply understand JS promises and I can't seem to find a simple answer on how in the world does it passes the value of the resolved to the handle success variable, I don't understand is that as a build method? But the name is (resolvedValue)

For example, I saw also in another example that they used (rejectionReason) to handle the rejected value, I want to understand how that happens.

here is the code:

```
    const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Yay!');
});
                      // this resolvedValue how does it happen? 
const handleSuccess = (resolvedValue) => {
  console.log(resolvedValue);
};
 
prom.then(handleSuccess); // Prints: 'Yay!'
```

Comment: I think [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-event-loop-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript) should help you in understanding promises more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets clarify on two different concepts:

1. Function Definition:

   ```
        const exampleFunction=(name)=>{console.log(name)} // just defined, does nothing
   ```
2. Function Invocation:

   ```
         exampleFunction("Erfan")  // logs "Erfan"
   ```

In JavaScript, function definitions can be passed to another function ("a higher order function") as a parameter, usually we describe such situation as "the function taking a callback".
The higher order function then calls the callback according to its own implementation, and may or may not pass a value to it.

In your example, method then of the the prom is the higher order function. it takes a callback, passes the resolve value to it, and calls it. it doesn't care about its name, just looks for a function definition and calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to got to [@Nirjal Paudel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13387913/nirjal-paudel) reference link, the answer to my question is :

**it happens by paassing it in the value as an anonymous function.**

Promises have a method called then that will run after a promise reaches resolve in the code. then will return the promise’s value as a parameter.

This is how you would return and log the value of the example promise:

```
   const handleSuccess = (resolvedValue) => {
  console.log(resolvedValue);
};
 
prom.then(handleSuccess);
```

The promise you created had a [[PromiseValue]] of 'Yay!'. This value is what will be passed into the **anonymous function** as a response

so this means that the name won't matter